# how to arrange columns in telerik grid in given custom style

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid, legend

When I click on ADD New button in Telerik Grid then I have to show the columns of the Grid as shown in the below image with boxes within a panel.

Please suggest me how can proceed

[image]

Also Are these called legend style

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming asp.net web forms and Telerik ASP.NET AJAX.  What you want to do is demonstrated in [this Telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/templateformupdate/defaultcs.aspx).  You can set:

```
<EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
                <FormTemplate>
```

And supply your own template to lay the UI out however you want.  You can also use a [user control](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/usercontroleditform/defaultcs.aspx).